# Multiple conditions in IF statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Is there a better way to do check the condition of AddressIndex?

```
if (AddressIndex == 104 || AddressIndex == 107 || AddressIndex == 108 || AddressIndex == 133 || AddressIndex == 155 || AddressIndex == 165 || AddressIndex ==  167 || AddressIndex == 168 || AddressIndex == 182 || AddressIndex == 214 || AddressIndex == 246 || AddressIndex == 260 || AddressIndex == 341 || AddressIndex == 345)

{

alert ("Sorry - We don't deliver to this address.");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @dsimer says, I think that's the best way to go.  It'd look something like:

```
switch AddressIndex {
  case 104:
  case 107:
  case 108:
  case ...:
  case ...:
    alert("Sorry - We don't deliver to this address.");
  break;
}
```

I need not enter all the numbers for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a [switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Comment: Any reason for the downrate?  I gave a valid answer - am I expected to write out an explanation and code code when I offer a direct reference link to a source that will present it better than I ever could?

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery:

```
var a = new Array(104, 107, 108, 133, 155,
                  165, 167, 168, 182, 214,
                  246, 260, 341, 345);
if($.inArray(AddressIndex, a))
{
    alert ("Sorry - We don't deliver to this address.");
}
```

Otherwise you can use the [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method:

```
var a = new Array(104, 107, 108, 133, 155,
                  165, 167, 168, 182, 214,
                  246, 260, 341, 345);

if(a.indexOf(AddressIndex) != -1)
{
    alert ("Sorry - We don't deliver to this address.");
}
```

And there's always a switch as a last resort:

```
switch(AddressIndex)
{
    case 104:
    case 107:
    case 108:
    case 133:
    case 155:
    case 165:
    case 167:
    case 168:
    case 182:
    case 214:
    case 246:
    case 260:
    case 341:
    case 345:
        alert ("Sorry - We don't deliver to this address.");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of performance a hash lookup would be fastest:

```
var nondelivery = {
  104: true, 107: true, 108: true, 133: true, 155: true,
  165: true, 167: true, 168: true, 182: true, 214: true,
  246: true, 260: true, 341: true, 345: true };

if( nondelivery[AddressIndex] )
  alert ("Sorry - We don't deliver to this address.");
```

This is of course only academic; a speed difference would only be noticed in a loop with many iterations.